# Any concrete advantages to using CSS .class instead of [attribute] selector?

Tags: css

In any modern browser (post IE 8), is there any reason to use CSS classes at all anymore, rather than just always use an attribute selector?

I bring this up because I'm working with AngularJS code, which is very attribute-driven, and I've found myself writing styles solely based on attributes rather than using classes, but that's not the norm and I'm wondering if there's a reason why.

Is there a hidden difference between the two that causes people to still use classes instead of attributes?

- Syntax: I would argue that `<bar foo>` and `<bar class="foo">` are roughly equivalent: both declared in the markup, both accessible to modify (add/remove) by JS, both have the same name structure.  Similarly, `[foo]{}` and `.foo{}` are all but equal.
- Both classes and attributes have the same [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), so CSS weights them the same.
- I have not been able to find sources citing performance concerns one way or the other.

So why are classes still around, when attributes already exist?  Is it just because they were there first and have stuck around?

Comment: What happens when you don't use `AngularJS` & still want to apply styles?

Comment: I can't say for certainty, but selecting by classes is almost definitely faster than by attributes. Nothing you would notice unless you are doing heavy dom querying.

Comment: Well, the flip side of saying that attributes are basically the same of classes, is that you don't give any reasons why they are better.  Makes sense that the community at large wouldn't make the jump for no real benefit.

Comment: I have a hunch that finding things by class would be _much_ faster, perhaps because the browser keeps an indexed list of elements with classes.  That's just a hunch though.

Comment: In response to the hold: that's fine, I got the answer I was looking for.  The browser does indeed treat class and attributes differently, at least from the perspective of speed, so there is a concrete reason to use classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider selector speed to be a pretty concrete reason.

http://jsperf.com/attribute-vs-class-selectors

[image]

Comment: And just as slow when searching by attribute name only: http://jsperf.com/attribute-vs-class-selectors/2

Comment: Sweet, thanks for that.  Accepting in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at this from a specific machine readability standpoint, but not from a human readability one.

Let's assume someone is working with a team of developers and designers on a project. Assigning a `class` to an element tells the human readers of the code that those elements belong to a certain group and that the group they belong to should have, relatively, the same styles. This makes referencing, maintaining and updating CSS style much simpler and faster.

`[attributes]` on the other hand, are almost like an inversion of a `class`. The element doesn't belong to the `[attribute]` like it belongs to a `class`, the `[attribute]` belongs to the element.

@Diodeus answer provides very concrete evidence when it comes to benchmarks, which IMO is the most important factor here, but don't forget about semantics either.